# how can I override the data that is rendered on shopify .liquid with the need for using Ajax

Tags: json, ajax, shopify, shopify-app

I have a use case where I want to implement custom search functionality for a Shopify site. So instead of using getting a `JSON` with `Ajax` and making a html and replacing the html. Is there a way where I can override the search.results data that the .liquid files are using.

So when I make a search in `/search?q=xyz`, I want to get the data from my `API`, and use that data to render the `product-item.liquid`. This way I don't have to worry about the UI of the `product-item` for different themes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can easily do this. You would install an App in your shop, and create an endpoint you would call with your search criteria. The end point is handled by a Shopify App Proxy, that securely allows you to callback the App. You could return Liquid as results, or just JSON as you wish. It is a standard and simple pattern for you to use.

See here: https://help.shopify.com/api/tutorials/application-proxies

Comment: Yeah. I came across this approach. The issue I see with this approach is  the, client will not have control over his product item UI  then ?  I was talking about the approach where user have their product-item.liquid and my app Will some how take that and renders the data based on the them of that site.

Comment: Not true. You can render Liquid as the response, and the client can mark that Liquid up as they see fit. Matching your variables for example. Experiment before you write it off. And you miss the fact you can always just return JSON. There is nothing wrong with this pattern for your use case, and you have no choice. So go with it.